How do you properly deploy from Azure Artifact Feed
I have an issue with my deployment/release process using Azure DevOps.
I have a Spring Boot API and I use Azure Pipelines to build the project and deploy it to my Artifact Feed. Using the SNAPSHOT version (I'm using Maven), the feed saves last 25 items, which in and of itself is fine. But the issue I have is when I create a new release (I'm also using Azure Release pipelines), it will take all the jar files from the feed for the SNAPSHOT version and deploy them to my App Service.

What I wanna know, is there a way for me to filter only the latest jar file during the release pipeline? I created a startup script which does that on the App Service, but deploys take like 10 minutes, because it uploads 5 GB of jar files each time.
The build pipeline is fine, and the release one is in the screenshots below.



Any and all help will be appreciated, thanks!

As of now, there is no functionality out-of-the-box to filter out the expected latest snapshot package to be downloaded during a release. The artifact file names cannot be referenced by any predefined release/artifacts variable, therefore the file naming pattern filter can only provide limited assistance.
The sample script is run to eliminate the unexpected snapshot packages after the default download of artifacts and before deployment. This will not reduce the time to download packages but can help you reduce the time for deployment.
tree

cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mvn

Get-Item "JavaAppDemoHelloAlvin*.jar" | Sort-Object -Descending Name | Select-Object -SkipIndex 0 | Remove-Item

tree





You're a genius, that was it! I don't mind the download (it's usually less than 1 minute), the issue is the later upload/deploy to app service took 10 or so minutes. Thank you!

As per Handling Maven snapshots:

When using Maven snapshots, multiple versions can be downloaded at once. You might need to remove the old versions and only keep the latest artifact before deployment.


Reading up a bit more on that, and on other StackOverflow threads, it seems that the command really only works locally, and also setting up automatic deletion on artifact feed isn't supported, so I don't think this will help.
